# Starting a webserver in a non-waiting process - Python

Tags: python, multithreading, process

So, I'm writing a integration test framework that consists in a back end plus a front end parts. The front end runs in `Ruby on Rails`, and I start it using a command line:

```
bundle exec thin start -p 3001 --ssl
```

I want to execute that command within its own process. Currently I use `subprocess`:

```
cmd = bundle exec thin start -p 3001 --ssl
subprocess.call([cmd])
```

However, `subprocess.call` will wait until the process returns (which it won't, since it's web server). What I need to have is the Rails server to run on it's own process. How can I have it done?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `subprocess.Popen`, it will start the process and allow you to comunicate with it if you want

more info:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

Answer (score 1):

It is almost the same as what you have, so I assume that it would be something like this:

```
arg = 'exec thin start -p 3001 --ssl'
bundle_pid = Popen(['/usr/bin/bundle', arg],close_fds=True).pid
```

Where bundle_pid is the process id of the spawned process.

Edit:
As "didn't work" doesn't give me a lot to go on, here is a mock up using libreoffice, as I do not have a ruby on rails set up.
Hopefully you will be able to pick the bones out of it.

```
from subprocess import call, Popen, PIPE
import os, signal
from os.path import expanduser
home_dir = expanduser("~/fs3")
#arg = home_dir+'/fs3.csv'
arg = ''
#pid = Popen(['/usr/bin/loffice', arg],close_fds=True).pid
pid = Popen(['/usr/bin/loffice', arg],close_fds=True).pid
n = 0
while n < 200000:
    n += 1
    print "still running", n
print pid
main_pid = os.popen('ps --no-headers -C soffice.bin').read(5)
print main_pid
repr(main_pid)
if main_pid != "":
    main_pid = int(main_pid)
    os.kill(main_pid, signal.SIGKILL)
n = 0
while n < 100000:
    n += 1
    print "still running 2", n
```